# Refresh WebSphere classpath for an EAR

Tags: java, websphere, classpath, classloader

I want to reduce the time spent waiting to bounce an EAR app on WebSphere each time I update one of the jars. Is there anyway I can refresh the classes/jars loaded for a specific EAR without stop/start?

WAS 7.0, Inside my EAR there are two WARs. The exploded EAR root dir holds these and all required jars. It's one of these jars that I want to update.

Comment: This is frequently known as hot deploy (usually with an exploded jar/war/ear) on other application servers.

Comment: Is it? According to http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdoc400/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.iseries.doc/info/ae/ae/trun_app_hotupgrade.html hot deploy refers to not having to restart the entire app server. I want to cut out the deployed EAR restart if possible.

Comment: Really?  That sounds just like a normal redeploy.  For open source application servers resources are watched and reloaded for these kind of applications.  Note however that the application server may be too dumb to be able to handle "oh a new jar" any other way than redeploying the EAR.  Note that you may be able to package your ear differently to help the app server (some things exploded, some not)

Comment: @user1561108 What modules do you have inside EAR? What is the version of WAS?

Comment: Have you tried a shared library instead? We share a few common JARs in a shared lib that loads on the application classpath. Everytime I drop a new version of the JAR into the lib, all the dependent WARs and EARs restart themselves.

Comment: restarting the ear takes a while, but if that's what I need to do then so be it. I'll take a look at shared libraries cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Run the server in debug mode, connect debugger from your IDE and rely on hotswapping of modified classes. This will not work in all cases, for example it won't when method signature is changed. Please check [Debugging applications](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/ttrb_debugwsa.html) on how to enable debug mode.
2. Do not package classes that you want to update inside JARs but put them into `WEB-INF/classes` directory inside WAR. Then you can replace them as needed in application's exploded directory. For server to pick up updated classes [Class loading and update detection](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/urun_rapp_classload.html) must be enabled.